# Oracle Make rows into columns with column value total

Tags: oracle

Good day All,

My Oracle sql query returns these values,

`20160801    TYPE1   14856
20160801    TYPE2   32543
20160801    TYPE3   32336
20160801    TYPE4   620
20160801    TYPE5   18
20160801    TYPE6   461705
20160801    NA      25
20160802    TYPE1   14828
20160802    TYPE2   32574
20160802    TYPE3   32285
20160802    TYPE4   621
20160802    TYPE5   18
20160802    TYPE6   461335
20160802    NA      25
20160803    TYPE1   14824
20160803    TYPE2   32593
20160803    TYPE3   32293
20160803    TYPE4   621
20160803    TYPE5   18
20160803    TYPE6   461752
20160803    NA      26`

How can I convert that to,

`TYPE  20160801 20160802 20160803 TOTAL
 =====================================
TYPE1   14856   14828   14824     44508
TYPE2   ... and so on
TYPE3
TYPE4
TYPE5
TYPE6`

All in one query.
Note 1. I looked into pivot but I don't want to manually list out the dates; it should be dynamic. 2. Not just limited to 3 days.

Thanks for any assistance here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic pivot in oracle sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491661/dynamic-pivot-in-oracle-sql)

Comment: If you want "dynamic" you will need to write dynamic SQL. Are you familiar with it? Or are you looking for someone else to write it for you? Then - dynamic SQL is generally not recommended, for a variety of reasons; many people use it when in fact they should use their reporting applications, which can do quick work of such requirements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make dynamic pivot in oracle PL SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32451072/how-to-make-dynamic-pivot-in-oracle-pl-sql)